# How to grant EFS mount target access to DataSync Agent on-premise?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-datasync

We have an on-premise DataSync agent (VM image) running, and an EFS with mount target.

We want to grant the agent access to the mount target in order to run sync tasks. However, there does not seem to be any security group assignable to the agent that we could grant egress access to the mount target.

So, currently, we grant public egress access to the mount target. Is there any way to nail this down to the agent?
If the agent was running on an EC2 instance, the instance itself could have a security group assigned, but there does not appear to be any alternative when the agent is running on-premise.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out, I had a misconception.

DataSync Locations have a security group assigned, which is used when running datasync tasks using that location. And that security group needs egress access in the EFS mount target's security group.